# FabricJS CurvedText object (extended) is not getting displayed on updating spacing and text properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have **updated fabric CurvedText** extension because of our requirement is something different. I want to set auto spacing between characters as it covers full circle. I got solutions after updating code in fabric CurvedText extension. While I am changing text of the object (on keyup event of textbox), I recalculate spacing and **setting that spacing and text via setText and set("spacing", val) properties**. In some situations, **I can not see object on canvas** but **I can see pointer of the object** on canvas mouse hover effect.

Remove characters from the textbox in this snippet and object will be hide after you will remove some characters.
Same thing happens when I add characters in the textbox.

[Updated curved text extension](http://www.trimantra.com/demo/fabric.curvedText_done.js).

```js
var radius = 100;
var circum = Math.floor(2 * Math.PI * radius);
var spacing = 0;
var fontFamily = 'Arial';
var fontSize = 30;

var text;
var lineHeight = 1;
var topa = 100;
var left = 200;

var char = 0;
var textWidth = 0;

var obj;
var canvas, ctx;

$(document).ready(function () {

    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    text = $('#uppertext').val();

    spacingOperation();

    var upperText = new fabric.CurvedText(text, {
        radius: radius,
        top: topa,
        left: left,
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
        fontSize: fontSize,
        lineHeight: lineHeight,
        spacing: spacing,
        originX: 'center',
        hasControls: true,
        hasBorders: true,
        selectable: true,
        textAlign: 'center'
    });
    canvas.add(upperText).renderAll();


    $('#uppertext').on('keyup', function () {
        text = $('#uppertext').val();

        setObjects();
        if (spacingOperation())
        {
            setProps();
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });
});


function spacingOperation() {
    textWidth = getTotalTextWidth();
    spacing = 0;
    textWidth = getTotalTextWidth();
    var diff = Math.ceil(circum - textWidth);
    spacing = Math.ceil(diff / char);
    return true;
}

function getTotalTextWidth()
{
    ctx.font = fontSize + 'px ' + fontFamily;
    char = text.length;
    txtWidth = Math.ceil(ctx.measureText(text).width + (spacing * char));
    return txtWidth;
}

function setObjects() {
    canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
    obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
}

function setProps() {
    obj.set('spacing', spacing);
    obj.setText(text);
    obj.setCoords();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trimantra.com/demo/fabric.curvedText_done.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row canvas-container" style="width: 50%; float: left;">
        <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px dotted #000;"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 150px;">
        Upper Text : <input type="text" id="uppertext" value="UTXXXXXXXXXXXXXUTXXXXXaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwXXXXXXXXUTXXXXXXXXXXXXXUTXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into you code and changed one line in fabric curvedtext extension from `ctx = new fabric.Canvas('c').getContext('2d');` to `ctx = fabric.util.createCanvasElement().getContext('2d');` and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: It is working perfectly but I can not understand the difference between these two lines for creating canvas context.